# how do i stop the flow of the program in c#?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Control cnt in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (cnt is TextBox)
    {
        if (cnt.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All fields are mandatory");

        }
    }
    else if (cnt is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)cnt;
        if (cmb.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All fields are mandatory");
            Application.Exit();

        }
    }
}

string gender;
string dob = cmbDate.Text + "/" + cmbMonth.Text + "/" + cmbYear.Text;
if (rbMale.Checked == true)
    gender = rbMale.Text;
else
    gender = rbFemale.Text;

query = "Insert into Admissions(Admission_date,Student_name,Father_name,Mother_name,DOB,Gender,Address,State, City,Pincode,Admission_for,Previous_school,Fees)values('" + txtAdmDate.Text + "','" + txtStudentName.Text + "','" + txtFatherName.Text + "','" + txtMotherName.Text + "','" + dob + "','" + gender + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtState.Text + "','" + txtCity.Text + "','" + txtPincode.Text + "','" + cmbClass.Text + "','" + txtPreviousSchool.Text + "','" + txtFees.Text + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
int admId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
```

When i leave out some fields and if i submit the form i get a message. But when i click OK the codes after foreach block also executes. How do I stop it from happening?

Comment: *"When i leave out some fields and if i submit the form i get a message."* -- please describe exactly what you mean: What fields? Where? What message?

Comment: If you want to exit a loop you can use the "break" keyword.

Comment: if i use break it will come out of that foreach loop and it also executes the code after foreach block. Please refer the code that i have attached

Comment: This code is full of mistakes; we don't know what `panel1` is. Is this a WinForm app? ASP.NET? You probably want to `return` after your `MessageBox.Show`, not `Application.Exit`. You need to learn how to [parameterize queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb) and how to [use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Application.Exit() has undesired side effects as no doubt you are seeing.  Try using a flag to guarantee you don't inadvertently run code after your stop condition.

```
var isExiting = false; 
foreach (Control cnt in  panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (cnt is TextBox)
            {
                if(cnt.Text==string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("All fields are mandatory");

                }
            }
            else if(cnt is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)cnt;
                if(cmb.SelectedIndex == -1)                
                {
                    isExiting = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("All fields are mandatory");
                    Application.Exit();

                }                      
            }
        }

    if(!isExiting){
        string  gender;
        string dob = cmbDate.Text + "/" +cmbMonth.Text + "/"+cmbYear.Text;
        if (rbMale.Checked == true)
            gender = rbMale.Text;
        else
            gender = rbFemale.Text;

        query = "Insert into Admissions(Admission_date,Student_name,Father_name,Mother_name,DOB,Gender,Address,State, City,Pincode,Admission_for,Previous_school,Fees)values('" + txtAdmDate.Text + "','" + txtStudentName.Text + "','" + txtFatherName.Text + "','" + txtMotherName.Text + "','" + dob + "','" + gender + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtState.Text + "','" + txtCity.Text + "','" + txtPincode.Text + "','" + cmbClass.Text + "','" + txtPreviousSchool.Text + "','" + txtFees.Text + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        con.Open();
        int admId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }//if !isExiting
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will try using it

Comment: there is a small issue in this code. If i leave all the fields the control does not get into first if block  if (cnt is TextBox)
            {
                if(cnt.Text==string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("All fields are mandatory");

                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom exceptions to control the flow of your application. Create a class that inherits from Exception

```
public class FieldAreMandatoryException : Exception {
}
```

and throw it when error occur. This will stop the flow of your application and trigger the catch block.

```
try
{
    foreach (Control cnt in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (cnt is TextBox)
        {
            if (cnt.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                throw new FieldAreMandatoryException(); //this will stop the flow and continue in the catch clause
            }
        }
        else if (cnt is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox) cnt;
            if (cmb.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                throw new FieldAreMandatoryException(); //this will stop the flow and continue in the catch clause
            }
        }
    }
    string gender;
    string dob = cmbDate.Text + "/" + cmbMonth.Text + "/" + cmbYear.Text;
    if (rbMale.Checked == true)
        gender = rbMale.Text;
    else
        gender = rbFemale.Text;
    query =
        "Insert into Admissions(Admission_date,Student_name,Father_name,Mother_name,DOB,Gender,Address,State, City,Pincode,Admission_for,Previous_school,Fees)values('" +
        txtAdmDate.Text + "','" + txtStudentName.Text + "','" + txtFatherName.Text + "','" +
        txtMotherName.Text + "','" + dob + "','" + gender + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" +
        txtState.Text +
        "','" + txtCity.Text + "','" + txtPincode.Text + "','" + cmbClass.Text + "','" +
        txtPreviousSchool.Text + "','" + txtFees.Text + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    int admId = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
}
catch (FieldAreMandatoryException exception) {
        Console.Log("All fields are mandatory!");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```